# advanced custom fields the_field without page_id

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I cant seem to get ACF to work when NOT using the page_id parameter. Here is what what my code looks like when it IS working:

'outreach' is the field_name and 10 is the page_id

```
<p><?php the_field('outreach', 10); ?></p>
```

when I do not include the page_id it doesn't work at all:

```
<p><?php the_field('outreach'); ?></p>
```

The documentation on the ACF website says you do not need the page_id parameter but I am using a multi site installation so I'm wondering if somehow that is messing things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't include the page ID then you'll need to ensure you're calling `the_field` from within [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

```
<?php 
// a page id is required here
the_field('outreach', 10);

if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

        // page id isn't required in here
        the_field('outreach');

    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try writing out the Page ID for that particular page and see what it is returning.

> ```
> //Page ID
> <?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>
> ```

Then you could use:

> ```
> <?php the_field('outreach', get_the_ID()); ?>
> ```